# Is there a way to register all touchEnded events, no matter how long the touch was?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to register all touch up through `touchesEnded`. It will only fire when there is a tap that lasts more than a second or two. Is there away to have it fire on all touch ups? It registers all `touchesBegan`.

Here is the simple code:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     NSLog(@"Touch Ended");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-touchesEnded:withEvent:` gets called even for brief touches, like taps. You probably have something in your responder chain that's handling the touch. For example, scroll views will normally delay touches until they figure out whether the user is trying to scroll, and gesture recognizers can also delay touch events. Specifically, UIGestureRecognizer has a `delaysTouchesEnded` property that may be interfering with your code.

Comment: All I have are some images on the screen so Im not sure that there could be interference. And the only UIGestureRecognizers I have are touchesBegan and touchesEnded so I am not sure where the delay is coming from.

Comment: `-touchesBegan:...` and `-touchesEnded:...` are methods, not gesture recognizers. Hard to know where you're going wrong without more information, but I added the `-touchesEnded:...` from your question to a view in a sample app, and it gets executed for every touch, no matter how long or short.

Comment: I had a tap gesture recognizer in my xib file. I thought it was necessary when actually it was causing the delay. My mistake, I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: NP, that's what SO is for.

Comment: Confusing a method with a gesture recognizer is obviously a very simple beginners mistake, do you know of a site that could teach me the language better so in the future I can avoid asking redundant questions?

Comment: I don't think *any* web site or other resource can prevent beginning mistakes -- they're an essential part of the learning process. But there are a lot of great resources out there: Apple's documentation is second to none, lots of very good blogs, and tutorial sites like [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.planetcocoa.org). Just keep reading, look at examples, and don't be afraid to try things yourself and ask questions when you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple touches are disabled by default. If you want to receive multiple touch events you must set the a `multipleTouchEnabled`  to YES of the view which you use. To do this in your `ViewDidLoad` just write `self.view.multipleTouchEnabled= YES` because it's just a property.

Another issue may be connected with Magic Trackpad because it adds a delay before it decides that you have ended a touch.Try to disable it : >System Preferences>Personal>Universal Access>Mouse & Trackpad>Trackpad Options>Ignore Trackpad when mouse is present.

Comment: I apologize, I am fairly new. How do you do that?

Comment: @user2593867 Do what?

Comment: set the a multipleTouchEnabled to YES

Comment: @user2593867 See my edits.Are you testing on simulator or real iDevice?

Comment: This did not work, I am working on a laptop so the trackpad could be the issue.

Comment: @user2593867 Yes. I think it is the only reason.As I already said "it adds a delay before it decides that you have ended a touch." Try to disable it and use a mouse may be it will help.

Comment: I had overlooked something in my xib file, that was the source of the delay. I apologize for wasting your time. Thank you for your help